# Custom Request Headers get removed, when an API is being called from browser

Tags: node.js, api, browser, http-post, webapi

We are using Node.js and trying to call an API (HTTP POST) from the application.
We are adding custom headers from the code, which are necessary in the API side.
When the request hits the API, the custom request headers are not available. We have enabled CORS from API side, but no luck. Please guide.

Comment: Same happens, when we use Angular frontend.

Comment: Can you validate where the headers are getting lost (client-side or server-side) ?

Comment: @Daniel they are getting lost in the browser itself

Comment: Can you please add which `HTTP Client` you are using (or framework) and a code snippet of using it (how do you add the extra headers)

Comment: earlier with {mode: no cors}, Headers were not coming out of browser, now they are coming out of browser, but blocked by API resource CORS policy

Comment: try sniffing the HTTP packets at the server-side to be 100% sure that the HTTP requests are reaching the server like they suppose to be. If It does and its a CORS issue    I would suggest adding a **reverse proxy** so both web-server and api-server will be on the same domain.